# CSS anchor under another, both empty to animate in javascript

Tags: css, jquery

Today i was fixing top buttons to move  hidden images.
I want to put a empty anchor under another one. Anchors used on javascript, and animate hidden images.

Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyDevv/TR4ps/4/

And here is the html, javascript and css, so u can understand better.

HTML

```
<div id="hidden-cartoons">
    <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-aEPxXvvzbgE/UJesTFlawfI/AAAAAAAAAz4/iYJpZwkkZ20/s228/velejador.png" class="cartoon velejador">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-SdWM2VqioyI/UJesVjjZ6WI/AAAAAAAAA0A/vStlRdYcEWA/s338/bodoleite.png" class="cartoon bodoleite">
</div>    
<div id="cartoons-buttons">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="left" id="velejador"></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="doSomething();" class="right"></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="left" id="bodoleite"></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="doSomething();" class="right"></a>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
#hidden-cartoons {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-99;
}

.cartoon {
    width:40px;
    position:absolute;
}
.cartoon.velejador {
    margin-top:10px;
    z-index:-99;
}

.cartoon.bodoleite {
    margin-top:60px;
    z-index:-99;
}   
#cartoons-buttons {
        width:320px;
        height:520px;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:100;
    } 
    .left {
        padding:20px;
        cursor:pointer;
        margin-right: 120px;
    }
    .right {
        padding:20px;
        cursor:pointer;
        margin-left: 120px;
    }
    #velejador {
        background-color:#00ff00;
    }
    #bodoleite {
        margin-top: 80px;
        background-color:#ff0000;
    }​
```

Javascript

> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> ```
> $('#velejador').mouseover(function() {
>     $('.velejador').stop().animate({
>         left: '+50',
>         width: '40px'
>     }, 1000);
> }).mouseout(function() {
>     $('.velejador').stop().animate({
>         left: '0',
>         width: '40px'
>     }, 1000);
> });
> $('#bodoleite').mouseover(function() {
>     $('.bodoleite').stop().animate({
>         left: '+50',
>         width: '40px'
>     }, 1000);
> }).mouseout(function() {
>     $('.bodoleite').stop().animate({
>         left: '0',
>         width: '40px'
>     }, 1000);
> }); });​
> ```

Comment: i have the 2 empty anchors bodoleite and velejador. bodoleite it's supposed to be over the .cartoon.bodoleite img but margin-top not working.

Comment: Both anchors are on same place, over .cartoon.velejador

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no space between the classes in your CSS.

```
.cartoon .bodoleite {
margin-top:60px;
z-index:-99;
}
```

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/TR4ps/32/

Not sure what the point of those .left and .right divs were. You needed to absolutely position the anchors and give them a height and a width. I think at least this is what you were after.

```
#hidden-cartoons {
position:absolute;
z-index:-99;
}

.cartoon {
width:40px;
position:absolute;
}
.cartoon.velejador {
margin-top:0px;
z-index:-99;
}

.cartoon.bodoleite {
margin-top:60px;
z-index:-99;
}   
#cartoons-buttons {
width:320px;
height:520px;
position:absolute;
z-index:100;
} 
#velejador {
position:absolute;
height:60px;
width:40px;
background-color:#00ff00;
float:left;
}
#bodoleite {
position:absolute;
background-color:#ff0000;
float:left;
height:100px;
width:40px;
top:60px;
}    ​
```

Comment: Their both at same place. I've changed the jsfiddle so now u can see better. Im trying to put green anchor over top image , and red anchor over bottom image. Here's the link for jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyDevv/TR4ps/13/

Comment: Thank you very much!! by the way, the point of left and right class its because ill have another animations on the right side of the div#cartoons-buttons.

Comment: Ahh okay, they didn't seem to serve a purpose. Glad I could help!